# How can I extract and count different phrases occurences in a file using a bash script?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a log file with text like that:

```
    "Blablabla" [texttext] "text" 148 228 "blabla" "phrase 1"
    "Blablabla" [texttext] "text" 220 211 "blabla" "phrase 1"
    "Blablabla" [texttext] "text" 148 215 "blabla" "phrase 2"
    "Blablabla" [texttext] "text" 220 245 "blabla" "phrase 3"
    "Blablabla" [texttext] "text" 200  -  "blabla" "phrase 4"
    "Blablabla" [texttext] "text" 148 200 "blabla" "phrase 4"
```

And I need to write script that will take only lines with first number 2** then extract "phrase X" and put their count and ratio in another file.

I thought to use something like that

```
    cat log.txt | grep '" 2..' > to something
```

But I can't figure out what sould I use - sed, awk or anything else. Also I think, I need to use bash arrays. But again, how can I use loops to find - is phrase already present or not?

Thanks for any help.

UPD. I need to see something like

```
1. Phrase 1 - 500 - 50%
2. Phrase 2 - 340 - 34%
3. Phrase 3 - 100 - 10%
4. Phrase 4 - 60 - 6%
```

And yeah, that's my bad, I've forgot. I need only Top-10 of those phrases.

Comment: Please provide an expected output.

Comment: and how was `500` calculated? The output is unclear

Comment: File has 10000+ lines. 500 times "phrase 1" was in the line with 2**.

Comment: @Mex, `500` can occupy `50%` of `1000`, not `10000+`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest No, no, no. That's not what I mean. There're not only phrase X lines. There're also random lines with more statements. So, it is LOG file. I need to extract certain lines of words and operate with them.

That's why I use regex.

Comment: Can the text within quotes contain spaces? Is the space between fields a blank char or a tab or something else? Your question is extremely unclear so YMMV wrt the usefulness of with whatever answer you get.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are referring to column 4 and that column only has 3-digit numbers:

```
cat line_with_input | grep -E '.*\s.*\s.*\s2[0-9]{2}.*' | awk '{print $7" "$8}' | sort | uniq -c
```

output in your case:

```
  2 "phrase 1"
  1 "phrase 2"
  1 "phrase 3"
  2 "phrase 4"
```

Edit: So you don't want to just count the different phrases?

Comment: don't over do it, won't `awk '$4~/.*2.*/{print $7"  "$8}' line_with_input` cut this down considerably? :-) . And "you don't just want to just count...?". Agreed. That's separate program! Good luck to all.

Comment: Not only. I need to sort by overall ratio/count and save only 10 lines. That's really my bad that I forgot to mention it.

Comment: @shellter, that is not only more elegant than my solution, but also actually doing what I wanted to do (my post is not doing what I intended it to do). Could you explain how exactly that awk statement works?

Comment: @Mex : calculating the ratio is a separate problem. You should try to solve it using awk associate arrays, i.e. `a["phrase 1"]++` (key is "phrase 1" value is an incrementing integer, and then post a new Q(IMHO). PejoPhylo: `$4~/.*2.*/` is a regular expression match on field 4 for `.*` (zero or more of any char), followed by a `2`, followed by zero or more any chars. So, basically, if $4 has a 2 in it, then process the block contained in `{print...}`

Answer (score 1):

For the particular input data in your question:

```
$ cat file1
    "Blablabla" [texttext] "text" 148 228 "blabla" "phrase 1"
    "Blablabla" [texttext] "text" 220 211 "blabla" "phrase 1"
    "Blablabla" [texttext] "text" 148 215 "blabla" "phrase 2"
    "Blablabla" [texttext] "text" 220 245 "blabla" "phrase 3"
    "Blablabla" [texttext] "text" 200  -  "blabla" "phrase 4"
    "Blablabla" [texttext] "text" 148 200 "blabla" "phrase 4"

$ awk '$4~/2../{l++;a[$7FS$8]++}END{print "total phrases:" l; \
for (i in a) print i,"-", "Found:",a[i],"-","Ratio:",a[i]/l*100 "%"}' file1

total phrases:3
"phrase 1" - Found: 1 - Ratio: 33.3333%
"phrase 3" - Found: 1 - Ratio: 33.3333%
"phrase 4" - Found: 1 - Ratio: 33.3333%
```

Obviously in this example total phrases refers to phrases found in lines that field 4 starts with 2

In order to get the top 10 , one easy way would be to run above code and then use sort + head :

```
$ awk 'your awk code here' file |sort |head #Head without options returns the top 10 lines.
```

PS: You need to adjust sort options to make a sorting based on ratio column or on phrases count column (awk output).